# How to delete row which contains specific id as text if I have table id tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with couple columns (one column has id as text). 
How to delete row which contains specific id as text if I have table id tag ?

Comment: Have you got an example of what you have, and what you want ? :)

Comment: You need to look at [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Comment: you also need to share the html structure and the value format you need to search within the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/wAxNu/)
refer this you will get idea.

```
remove(); // by using remove you can remove row
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this thing you are looking for?

if you want to delete onclick of button which is present in a row, will be like:

```
<td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
```

and your jquery will be like:

```
$('table.mytable').on('click', '.delete', function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); 
$(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```